# Convert helper to model method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I use this following helper:

```
function whereHasNested($query, $key, $relationship)
{
    if(Input::has($key))
    {
        $callback = function($q) use (&$relationship, &$key, &$callback) {
            if(!$relationship) $q->whereId(Input::get($key));
            else $q->whereHas(array_shift($relationship),$callback);
        };

        $callback($query);
    }
}
```

This will avoid to have to write multiple **whereHas** within **whereHas**. Here is a usage example:

```
$query = Model::query();

whereHasNested($query, 'package_id', ['club', 'membership', 'package']);

return $query->orderBy('update_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

However, how could I convert this to a method in my **BaseModel**?

So I could chain it like:

```
$query->whereHasNested($key, $relationship);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) are for:

```
public function scopeWhereHasNested($query, $key, $relationships)
{
    // your code here...
}

// then use it wherever you want

Model::whereHasNested($key, $relationships);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip Mr. Silber, it works like a charm.